# How can this deterministic linear time selection algorithm be linear?

Tags: algorithms, sorting

I'm trying to understand the basic concepts of algorithms through the classes offered at [Coursera](http://www.algo-class.org) (in bits and pieces), I came across the deterministic linear time selection algorithm that works as follows:

- Select(A,n,i)

  1. If n = 1 return A[1].
  2. p = ChoosePivot(A, n)
  3. B = Partition(A, n, p)
  4. Suppose p is the jth element of B (i.e., the jth order statistic of A). Let the “ﬁrst part of B” denote
     its ﬁrst j − 1 elements and the “second part” its last n − j elements.

     - If i = j, return p.
     - If i < j, return Select(1st part of B, j − 1, i).
     - Else return Select(2nd part of B, n − j, i − j).

And sorts the array internally in the `ChoosePivot` subroutine to calculate the median of median using a comparison based sorting algorithm. But isnt the lower bound on comparison based sorting `O(nlogn)`? So how would it be possible for us to acheive `O(n)` for the entire algorithm then? 
Am I missing something here?

Comment: Are you *sure* that's what `ChoosePivot` does?

Comment: Yeah `ChoosePivot` computes the median of medians of the original array for which it employs comparison based sorting, which theoretically has a worst case of `O(nlogn)` if Im not mistaken

Comment: There's no mention of sorting whatsoever. There is partitioning. Most of the array will be unsorted when the algorithm finishes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> And sorts the array internally in the ChoosePivot subroutine to calculate the median of median using a comparison based sorting algorithm.

This is the incorrect premise (you are right that if we *did* do a comparison-based sort, we couldn't be linear). The point of median-of-medians is that it *is* linear - you don't need to sort the whole set if all you want is the median. See [proof of O(n) running time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians#Proof_of_O.28n.29_running_time) on wikipedia for more detail.